# Div width change with Jquery on scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to change my `#opacity-div` width when the user scrolls down the webpage. If the user scrolls down to `.paralax`, the `#opacity-div` should get a width of `200px`. When the user scrolls up past `.paralax` the `#opacity-div` should get a width of `550px`, which is the default width of the div.

Currently `.animate` is used for a smother transition. The jQuery code works when the user scrolls down and the div gets a width of `200px` with a smooth transition, but when the user scrolls back up the width of the `#opacity-div` will not change to `550px` again.

Here is parts of the code used:

**HTML**

```
<div id="startsidabild">
  <div id="opacity"> </div>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li id="hemscroll">Hem</li>
      <li id="menyscroll">Meny</li>
      <li id="kontaktscroll">Kontakt</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="images/pizza2.jpg" alt="pizzabild" class="img-responsive images">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="images/pizza1.jpg" alt="pizzabild" class="img-responsive images">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script>
    $('#myCarousel').carousel({
      interval: 2000
    })
  </script>
</div>
<div class="paralax">
  <h1>PARALAX</h1> </div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var targetOffset = $(".paralax").offset().top;
  var $w = $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($w.scrollTop() > targetOffset) {
      $("#opacity").animate({
        width: "200px"
      });
    } else {
      $("#opacity").animate({
        width: "550px"
      });
    }
  });
});
```

**CSS**

```
#opacity {
width:550px;
position:fixed;
height:100vh;
background: linear-gradient(to right, black, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
opacity: 1;
filter: Alpha(opacity=100);
z-index:1;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, your comparison `if($w.scrollTop() > targetOffset)` ignores the window height.

`.scrollTop()` = hidden pixels above the top-scrollable area.
 `offset().top` = is relative to the document.

What you should be comparing is,
`$('.paralax').offset().top - $(window).height()` (scrolling needed to make .paralax visible)
 vs
 
`$(window).scrollTop()` current scrolling

so following code will check whether current scrolling is greater than the the scrolling needed to display .paralax

```
var targetOffset = $(".paralax").offset().top;
var winHeight    = $(window).height();

$(window).scroll(function(){
   var currentScroll = $(window).scrollTop();         // current Window scrollTop
   var scrollNeeded  = (targetOffset - winHeight);    // scroll needed to make .paralax visible
   $("#opacity").width(function(){
      return ( currentScroll < scrollNeeded ) ? 550 : 200 ; 
   }); 

});
```

---

Since jQuery `scroll()` is currently called, attaching animate() to this event will drain the memory out. Let's use css `transition` property as below (See updated demo as well)

```
#opacity {
   ...
   -webkit-transition: width 2s;
   transition: width 2s; 
   ...
```

[See Demo](http://codepen.io/CreativeCreate/pen/qZmwOg?editors=1010)

Comment: how could i add .animate to this?